# How to use in function block diagram last value selected

Tags: plc

I got an interesting "homework" and I can't figure it out. Is it possible to create an application in FBD PneuAlpha for the following request?

> There is a light bulb in the room and two switches that control it: `S1` and `S2`. The bulb shall follow the last command of the switches

e.g:

`S1 OFF`, `S2 OFF` => bulb `OFF`

`S1 OFF`, `S2  ON` => bulb `ON`

`S1  ON`, `S2  ON` => bulb `ON`

`S1  ON`, `S2 OFF` => bulb `OFF`

---

I succeeded in doing a program that keeps the light on as long as there is at least one on, but i can't do it to remember it's last state.

---

I tried to think about it as a FSM with two states `ON` and `OFF` and there are:

- If i am in `state 0`(led `OFF`) if input is `00` stay on `state 0`, if input is `01` `10` or `11` go to `state 1` (led `ON`)
- if I am in `state 1`(led `ON`) if input is `11` stay on `state 1`, if input is `00`, `01`, `10` go to `state 0` (lef `OFF`)

I'm not sure this is right, but i didn't succed in finding the boolean equation for my FSM.

p.s i would like to know how to do this with simple logic gates, and then i will convert to some predefined function that the `pneuAlpha` program has.

Comment: You'll need to only respond to inputs on change.  So you'll need to compare inputs current scan value with last scan value.  Note your FSM, as written, for inputs 01 and 10 will oscillate between states

Comment: I'd use the PULSE block with some logic, and the SET/RESET

Comment: @chrisneilsen but this can be turned into a FSM ? Could you show me a valid one?

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as before.   Use PULSE to transition only on the rising (to On) or falling (to Off) edges of the switch inputs

Comment: i need a way to follow the succession, like a closed loop somewhere.

Comment: @chrisneilsen you were right. I modified my questions and added the answer. But another question came in my mind. Can I do the same thing using only boolean logic?

Comment: @catalina on SO when you want to post an answer to a Q, even your own,  pls post an Answer rather that editing it into the Q.  BTW,  I can give you a state machine, which I'm sure you can implement as logic gates

Comment: thank you, ies, i would like a FSM but with the mention that i'm not sure i can extract the equation.

Comment: @catalina this is _not_ a 2 way light circuit (if thats what your tutor is asking for then we've both missinterpreted it)  A 2 way light would be `Lamp = XOR(Sw1, Not Sw2)`

Comment: the one with XOR was implemented by the students very fast, and then he said "now try to do this"(the one that follows the last switched latch) and no body succeeded

Comment: @chrisneilsen i still couldnt solve the FSM table. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

To implement in State Machine, you'll need states to differentiate the switch conditions that could be either lamp On or Lamp Off, in tha diagram below

> Step 00 - Sw1 = 0, Sw2 = 0, Lamp = 0
>   Step 01 - Sw1 = 0, Sw2 = 1, Lamp = 1
>   Step 02 - Sw1 = 1, Sw2 = 0, Lamp = 1
>   Step 03 - Sw1 = 0, Sw2 = 1, Lamp = 0
>   Step 04 - Sw1 = 1, Sw2 = 0, Lamp = 0
>   Step 05 - Sw1 = 1, Sw2 = 1, Lamp = 1

I've left out the transitions where both sw's change on the same scan.  While unlikely to occur, for completeness sake you should add them.  Sw's 00 -> 11 and 11 -> 00 are clear, but  01 -> 10 and 10 -> 01 are not defined in your problem spec.

[image]

Comment: supposing the latches can't be changed simultaneously. Got it!

Comment: there is a mistake from S03 to S0

Comment: @catalina yes S03 to S00 should be `00`

Comment: I wrote the table I didn't succeed in getting the equation

Answer (score 0):

I followed chris neilsen answer related to the PneuAlpha FBD diagram solution and he was right. The program works exactly as I wanted to:

[image]

I asked him again if I can implement the same thing using only boolean logic, and he provided me a FSM diagram.

The table for the FSM. I'm not sure 100% this is right, but following *chris neilsen*'s diagram, this is what I came up with:
[image]